# MFC: How to receive ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI for a CTabView itself?

Tags: mfc

I have an SDI Document/View MFC app the wizard created with several different windows (workspace, properties, view, output).   My main view `CMyView` is derived from a `CTabView`.

I want to offer a "Close Tab" option via the toolbar, menus and context menus, but `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` from within `CMyView` is not called, my guess is it's probably going to whatever view is in a tab but there are several different types of views that can be opened in a tab so I want `CMyView` to handle it in one place.

To me, having it handled in the `CTabView` makes the most sense design wise, but maybe I'll have to do it in the mainframe and then call a method of the view to get the result.  But I thought I'd check here with people with more experience using MFC.  What is the best way to handle it?

Comment: This should not be a problem. Show us some code what you have tried.

Comment: I'm not sure what to show, I did verify "my guess" is correct.  When I add the  `ON_COMMAND(ID_TAB_REFRESH, &OnTabRefresh)` and `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_TAB_REFRESH, &OnUpdateTabRefresh)` to one of the views that is a tab, the calls were made as soon as the a tab with that view was open.   So it must have to do with `CTabView` sending everything to the view instead of processing it itself?

Comment: actually the reason is the frame sends it to the active view, which is the view in a tab, not the ctabview itself.  I don't know how to format comments but the frame code is: `CView* pView = GetActiveView();  if (pView != NULL && pView->OnCmdMsg(nID, nCode, pExtra, pHandlerInfo))  return TRUE;`  Is there a way for the CTabView to get it?

Comment: Yes, there is. On your class you derive from `CFrameWnd` you can do the same thing, but for your `CTabView`. `CTabView* pTabView = GetYourActiveTabView();  if (pTabView != NULL && pTabView->OnCmdMsg(nID, nCode, pExtra, pHandlerInfo))  return TRUE; else return FALSE;` It is called rerouting. But normally, implementing it should be the exception, not the rule.